# Why does my screen fade effect only happen once?

Tags: javascript, fade, fadeout, effects, effect

I wrote a screen fade effect that starts the screen red and fades to black. When the code is called, it works correctly - only once; afterwards the effect fails and I don't know why.

```
export class FadeEffects {
    constructor(game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.width = 640;
        this.height = 480;
        this.fadeFinished = false;
        this.fade = 255;
    }//constructor()

    //this fade effect starts red transparent and fades to black
    fadeRed() {

        //now make the rectangle fade to black
        let fadeOut = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('in interval');
            this.fade -= 1;
            //when finished
            if (this.fade === 0) {
                this.fade = 255;
                this.fadeFinished = true;
                clearInterval(fadeOut);
            }//fade check
        }, 25);//fadeIn interval

        return this.fadeFinished;
    }//fadeRed()

    draw(context) {
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.fade + ", 0, 0, 0.5";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }//draw()
}//class FadeEffects
```

Then in the calling function the object of FadeEffects is instantiated and toRemove is set to TRUE and fadeFinished is set to false. Then this code is called:

```
if(!this.fadeFinished && toRemove === 'TRUE'){
            this.fadeFinished = this.fadeEffect.fadeRed();
            this.fadeEffect.draw(context);
        }
```

Then when ready, fadeFinished is set to false again. But for some reason the effect only works the first time.

Comment: what is fadeFinished supposed to do? seems me it would start out true, then once the fade function starts its set to false, then once the fade is finished you set it to true again. so a) I don't understand why its set false in the constructor (rather than at the beginning of the fadeRed function) and b) you say "Then in the calling function the object of FadeEffects is instantiated and toRemove is set to TRUE and fadeFinished is set to false" but you didn't post that code, so I'm not really sure what this is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fadeRed` function should invoke your `draw` function at each iteration.  I would consider passing the `context` to your constructor, and letting `draw` reference it internally.

Here's a working test page.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvas { width: 640; height: 480; }
</style>
<script>
class FadeEffects {
    constructor(game, context) {
        this.game = game;
        this.width = 640;
        this.height = 480;
        this.fadeFinished = false;
        this.fade = 255;
        this.context = context;
    }//constructor()

    //this fade effect starts red transparent and fades to black
    fadeRed() {
        //now make the rectangle fade to black
        let fadeOut = setInterval(() => {
            console.log('in interval');
            this.fade -= 1;
            this.draw();
            //when finished
            if (this.fade === 0) {
                this.fade = 255;
                this.fadeFinished = true;
                clearInterval(fadeOut);
            }//fade check
        }, 25);//fadeIn interval

        return this.fadeFinished;
    }//fadeRed()

    draw() {
        this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.fade + ", 0, 0, 0.5";
        this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }//draw()
}//class FadeEffects
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
const canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
const context=canvas.getContext('2d');
const rect=new FadeEffects(null, context);
rect.fadeRed();
rect.fadeRed();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I implemented the change and it still only does the effect once. It's weird.

Comment: I just added some working test code.  You should be able to use it to locate any material differences

Comment: Strangely that didn't work either. The problem I'm having doesn't seem to be the interval, but the rectangle stops drawing after the first complete fade, and it never fades again.